# unresolved external symbol __imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12 referenced

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I want to write a C++ program which calls Java method.

I am trying to invoke a Java function from C++. As described here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html

but I get this error while debugging and can not handle it. 
I m using Visual studio 2012.
Here is my code C++ code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <jni.h>       /* where everything is defined */

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Users\\yv\\workspace\\JNI\\bin";    // my class is under this directory. 

vm_args.version = 0x00010006; 
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;

/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
 * pointer in env */
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);  // I got err msg "cannot convert parameter 2 from 'JNIEnv **' to 'void **' " so added (void **) as described in some other sources    

delete options;
jvm->DestroyJavaVM();


return 0;
}
```

Java installed on my comp version is
C:\Users\yv>JAVA -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

and my java code in case of need.

```
public class jniClass {
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    System.out.println("Arguments sent to this program:");
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("(None)");
    } else {
        for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(args[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. 
The error:

```
unresolved external symbol _imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM@12 referenced
```

is because the jvm.lib is not being linked with.

It can be solved by two ways.

First link to jvm.dll  dynamically at run time, by using LoadLibrary:

```
 HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("D:\\desired_jvm\\jre6\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll"));
 typedef jint (JNICALL *PtrCreateJavaVM)(JavaVM **, void **, void *);
 PtrCreateJavaVM ptrCreateJavaVM = (PtrCreateJavaVM)GetProcAddress(hinstLib,"JNI_CreateJavaVM");
 jint res = ptrCreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

Second is link the jvm.lib to your project.

Right click on the project -> properties.

On the Properties dialog box

add jvm.lib under Linker->Input->AdditionalDependencies area.

And write jvm.lib path under Linker->General->AdditionalLibraryDirectories

Comment: for what it's worth I found that there's a jvm.lib in my jdk installation (java 1.6) which is about 299k and a jvm.lib in my jre installation which is about 553k. When I link with the version in the jdk library I get this unresolved external, when I use the lib from the jre, it links without error. Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: ^YES YES IT DOES. I love you. :)

Answer (score 5):

I solved the error:

```
unresolved external symbol _imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM@12 referenced
```

by installing the correct version of JDK for the application configuration. I installed 64-bit version  of JDK on Windows 7 (64-bit) machine. However, my application was 32-bit. I un-installed the 64-bit JDK version and installed the 32-bit. Afterwards there was no linking error.

Comment: for me the solution was this, indeed, but no need to uninstall the 64-bit version, just fix dependencies paths to point to "x86" program folder.

Answer (score 3):

The error:

> unresolved external symbol _*imp*_JNI_CreateJavaVM@12 referenced

is because the `jni.lib` is not being linked with: *add it to the list of libraries to link with* (not sure where as I am unfamiliar with the VS IDE. The path where the `jni.lib` file resides will also need specified somewhere).

Note that `new[]` must be `delete[]`d, not `delete`d (there appears to be no reason to be dynamically allocating memory).

Comment: 1) Should I add it to Java or C++ program. 
2) I searched my C drive and could not find any jni.lib file to add it to the list of libraries to link.

Comment: @HorasanLee, add it to C++ and is will be under `$JAVA_HOME\lib`.

Comment: No jni.lib file anywhere. I unistalled Java 1.7  and installed 1.6 nothing changed. No jni.lib file around to specify the path.

Comment: hmjd Thank you very much for your answer and support but it was to be **"jvm.lib"** instead of **"jni.lib"**.