# where can I find jni.lib

Tags: visual-studio-2010, java-native-interface

I have the same question like this one  [unresolved external symbol __imp__JNI_CreateJavaVM@12 referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714754/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-jni-createjavavm12-referenced/18714935#18714935)

but No jni.lib file around in  $JAVA_HOME\lib.
And I cant find jni.lib anywhere, where can I find it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>
using std::cerr;
int jvmtest(){
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVM *jvm;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];
    options[0].optionString = 
       "-Djava.class.path=H:\\source";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized=0;
    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm,(void **)&env,&vm_args);
    if(res <0)
    {//do something
    }
     jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
     return 0;
   }
```

and in the vs2010,

> library directory is C:\jdk\lib;$(LibraryPath)
>
> include path is C:\jdk\include\win32;C:\jdk\include;$(IncludePath)

Comment: Well, where did you get your JNI from?

Comment: I have added my c++ source code to the question.  I am trying to invoke a Java function from C++.

Comment: Yes, but where did your JNI library come from? You've got a folder with jni.h in it right? Where did that come from. Start there and look in ../lib.

Comment: jni.h is in C:\jdk\include and I cant find jni.lib in c:\jdk\lib. Do you think there is something wrong with the jdk1.6.0_23? I am downloading jdk7 and then check whether there is jni.lib in it.

Comment: still cant find jni.lib in the corresponding directory of jdk7

Answer (score 1):

Try `jvm.dll`. This file may locate in `$JAVA_HOME/bin/client` or `$JAVA_HOME/bin/server`.
Find it and append the containing path into your `LIBRARY`.

Comment: well, I change the way to load jvm.dll. by calling the funtion like this `HINSTANCE hVM = LoadLibrary("C:\\jdk\\jre\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll");`, linking error disappeared. The answer is here [linke-error](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/263687/Linker-error-undefined-reference-to-_imp__JNI_Crea)