# ERROR LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM12 referenced while building hadoop 3.2.1

Tags: java, c++, hadoop, java-native-interface

I am trying to compile and build hadoop 3.2.1 on windows 10 by following [this tutorial](https://kontext.tech/column/hadoop/378/compile-and-build-hadoop-321-on-windows-10-guide#section_i_installation_guide_1). I have executed this command for doing that:

```
mvn package -Pdist -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true
```

The following error has occured:

```
 [exec] jni_helper.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non rÚsolu __imp_JNI_CreateJavaVM rÚfÚrencÚ dans la fonction getGlobalJNIEnv [C:\hdp\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs-native-client\target\native\main\native\libhdfs\hdfs.vcxproj]
     [exec] jni_helper.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non rÚsolu __imp_JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs rÚfÚrencÚ dans la fonction getGlobalJNIEnv [C:\hdp\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs-native-client\target\native\main\native\libhdfs\hdfs.vcxproj]
     [exec] C:\hdp\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs-native-client\target\native\bin\RelWithDebInfo\hdfs.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 externes non rÚsolus [C:\hdp\hadoop\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs-native-client\target\native\main\native\libhdfs\hdfs.vcxproj]
```

I opened the solution in `visual studio 2010` and tried to build it but i had the same errors.

The error `LNK1120` has occured because of the error `LNK2019` (according to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2019?view=vs-2019)), so i tried to find a solution.
I have found some solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714754/unresolved-external-symbol-imp-jni-createjavavm12-referenced) which shows that the error `LNK2019` occurs because the `jvm.lib` is not being linked with the project.

I have checked in `Linker->Input` that the `jvm.lib`is linked to the project. I added to `Linker->Command line` the command `/VERBOSE` to be sure that the `jvm.lib` is linked to the project during the build but the error is still occuring.

I have `JDK1.8.0_181` installed on my machine. The folder `JDK1.8.0_181/bin` is in `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Maybe the `jvm.lib` is not compatible with your old version of Visual Studio. Maybe you are mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Both `jvm.lib` (in the JDK folder) and the visual studio installation folder are in `C:\Program Files (x86)`  which means that both of them are 32bit.

Comment: Visual Studio is always in x86 even though it can build 64 bit. However the default should be 32 bit.

Comment: The tutorial you're following is for 64-bit (note: a 32-bit hadoop makes very little sense, unless you plan to use 2 GB of RAM or less).

Comment: Yes you're right because i'm executing the command for building projects in  `Visual Studio x64 Win64 Command Prompt (2010)` . So should i install the 64bits java version?

Comment: Yes that means you want 64 bit java and want to link to a 64 bit java library.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try

Comment: I have installed the 64 bits JDK version and the problem is resolved. Thank you so much.